# What is the maximum retirement age of cricket player?

Tags: rules, cricket

Many player retire from cricket at their on choice, but if they do not do it then what is the maximum age as specified by the respective cricket board until a player can play cricket and after that they will be retired officially by the cricket board?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the maximum retirement age of cricket player?

There is no retirement age. It's always a decision by the person itself and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, no cricket board enforces a mandatory retirement age. I know players who kept playing into their sixties, and I'm sure there are players who kept going longer than that.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with you . Cricket has no age limit for retirement. A player can retire at the earliest of his/her career or go as long as his/her body supports.For example, Australian player ***George Bradley Hogg*** play at the age of ***47***.

Indian player ***Pravin Tambe*** Made his IPL debut at the age of 41 and represented IPL team SRH(SunRisers Hyderabad) in 2017. However he was unsold in IPL 2018 auction.